# How to dynamically populate columns smart table Angular 9?

Tags: angular

I have two tables, Users and Vehicles with their respective values.
I have a smart-table with current code in ts like this:

```
settings = {
add: {
  addButtonContent: '<i class="nb-plus"></i>',
  createButtonContent: '<i class="nb-checkmark"></i>',
  cancelButtonContent: '<i class="nb-close"></i>',
  confirmCreate: true,
},
edit: {
  editButtonContent: '<i class="nb-edit"></i>',
  saveButtonContent: '<i class="nb-checkmark"></i>',
  cancelButtonContent: '<i class="nb-close"></i>',
  confirmSave: true,
},
delete: {
  deleteButtonContent: '<i class="nb-trash"></i>',
  confirmDelete: true,
},
columns: {
  
  identifier: {
    title: 'Steam',
    type: 'string',
  },
  license: {
    title: 'Licencias',
    type: 'string',
  },
  money: {
    title: 'Dinero',
    type: 'number',
  },
  name: {
    title: 'Nombre',
    type: 'string',
  },
  group: {
    title: 'Trabajo',
    type: 'string',
  },
},
```

};

and loading the data like this:

```
source: LocalDataSource = new LocalDataSource();
constructor(private tjUsuarioService: TjususariosService) {
this.tjUsuarioService.UsuariosListado().subscribe(
  
  res => {
    this.usuarios = res;
    
    this.settings = Object.assign({}, this.settings);
    this.source.load(this.usuarios);
    
    console.log(res)
  },
  err => console.log(err),

);
```

}
My idea is to use a single smart-table for Vehicles and Users, filling it in according to the data that comes from the request.
Thank you all.

Comment: Are you talking about https://akveo.github.io/ng2-smart-table

Comment: Yes, exactly from that table

Comment: I'm not quite clear. Are you trying to merge two tables into one?
Can you please share at least one User and Vehicle data?

Comment: It is not merging, it is depending on the table that the user chooses to view, load the data of users or vehicles, but in the same table

Comment: Check out the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I've created a demo at [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/example-ng2-smart-table-pzagda?file=src/app/app.component.ts).

So, you have to create column collections for both users and vehicles collection.
Then you have to call API based on selection and then load data.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I already have it functional.
Thanks !!